# Jquery selects svg text, but css not applying

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, svg, snap.svg

I first tried [textillate](http://jschr.github.io/textillate/) to get it work with snap.svg. Jquery is selecting text properly and even modifying it properly. After looking at Textillate, I found its using [animate.css](https://github.com/daneden/animate.css) internally for animations. So, I decided to use animate.css directly to see if it works.

Code eg. :

```
var text = s.text(500,500,"sample text");
text.attr({
fontSize :44,
fill : 'red',
 "id" : "myText"
});
```

and then :->

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("svg").ready(function(){
 $('#myText').text("hello");
$('#myText').addClass('animated bounceOutLeft'); //animate.css part
});
});
```

Animate.css and Textillate are working fine on normal html elements. Since, jquery is selecting svg text element properly and even changing text, I am not sure problem exists in which part of the code.

More info :

1)From the direct css, I have added "class" and set properties in css like color etc, and it works.

2) if I add "class" : "animated bounceOutLeft" directly in svg, it works.

Edit :

jsfiddle :

http://jsfiddle.net/s2tw7rkc/

Comment: have you sure that the `svg` element is ready after the `document` element is ready ?

Comment: not sure. how make I make sure. I added $("svg").ready(function(){ , and inside it I change text from "sample text" to "hello" and it changes. so I guess, its loading.

Comment: Any chance you could get it testing on a jsfiddle ?

Comment: created here : http://jsfiddle.net/s2tw7rkc/